# Access Denied error when trying to get mouse position

Tags: java, mouse

I am attempting to get the X and Y position of my mouse using MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation(); but I get a java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.awt.AWTPermission" "watchMousePointer") error.

Any help would be great...

Here is my code; error message is on the bottom of code: http://pastebin.com/46eRXgmi

Thanks!

Comment: Please paste the relevant parts of the code and error message into your question itself, rather than using an external resource.

Comment: I have no clue what you are actually trying to do but it seems like you are trying to gather mouse movements.  Wouldn't it be better to immplement [`MouseMotionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseMotionListener.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is that you must add a `MouseListener` to the component which will report the click locations:

[Tutorial to implement MouseListner , which will tell you about the position.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)